# Handling lvalue and rvalue references uniformly

Tags: c++

I have two related questions, both related to how to handle lvalue and rvalue references uniformly.

### Virtual function case:

```
struct Foo {
    Object m_object;

    virtual void bar(SomeRefTypeOfObject object);
};
```

Basically, what I want to achieve is to have a `SomeRefTypeOfObject`, which is able to store both lvalue and rvalue reference to `Object`. `bar` is a larger function, and it will use one `m_object = object;` statement store the value of `object` (a copy or move operation, depending on the type of the stored reference). The reason is that I want to avoid having two `bar` functions (for each reference type). Is there anything in the standard library which can do this conveniently and efficiently, or do I have to roll my own solution for this? If I have to roll my own solution, how would a good implementation look like?

### Template function case:

```
struct Foo {
    Object m_object;

    template <...>
    void bar(... object);
};
```

I'd like to have a `bar` template, which can be called with any kind of `Object` or its derived classes/other objects which can be converted to `Object` (like if `bar` were two overloaded functions with `const Object &` and `Object &&` parameters), but instantiated with **only** `const Object &` and `Object &&`. So, I don't want to have `bar` instantiated for each derived type. What is the most clear way to do that? I suppose I'll need some form of SFINAE here.

Note: `m_object = object;` assignment can happen in a function which is called by `bar`. So the solution passing object by value is not optimal, as unnecessary copies/moves will be made (there can be types for which move is not that cheap as passing down a reference). Furthermore, the assignment can happen in a conditional way, so passing object by value just in the leaf function not a solution (because it can be runtime dependent, which function does the actual assignment).

Comment: Perfect forwarding with virtual... maybe the type erasure + visitor pattern could do it...

Comment: The typical solution in both cases is to take type `Object` because that handles both temporaries and non-temporaries correctly with the overhead of 1 move. Unless you can't do that because `Object` is abstract.

Comment: @nwp: Thanks for the advice. This solution works OK, when the assignment happens in bar. But, the assignment could happen in a function call deeper. And I don't want to have a copy each time I pass down object. Maybe I'll edit the question to make this clear.

Comment: Also you could use a public `template <> bar()` which would move/copy the parameter to `m_object` and then call a private virtual `bar_imp()`.

Comment: Why would you need a copy to hand it down? Just pass `std::move(object)` to the next function call which prevents the copy.

Comment: @nwp: oops, you're right. However, it gets kinda inconvenient. With my desired reference type, it would be convenient. Plus, there can be objects for which move is not that cheap.

Comment: @nwp: I'm not saying that your solution is bad, maybe I'll use this method if no good answer arrives for the question, so thanks for suggesting this!

Comment: Have you read about [universal references](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers)?

Comment: @jdehesa Forwarding references don't help because they require templates which are incompatible with `virtual`.

Comment: @nwp So, maybe, @geza could avoid the public virtual interface (http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm) turning the interface into a template with universal references (forwarding the parameter to `m_object`) and turning the public virtuals into private ones (taking no parameters)?

Comment: @Tarc: I need to pass object to derived classes, so unfortunately this doesn't work

Comment: @geza , that's not a problem: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a5b9596ef014dcb

Comment: @Tarc, yes, it can be solved in certain cases, but not all. Sometimes, object will not be stored directly in an m_object, but in an array, which only present in the derived class. m_object in the class was just an example.

Comment: regarding the second question, sould bar(x) call bar(Object const&) for an x of type derived from Object ? ( it seems not as you asked it, but this would go against Liskov substitutability ... )

Answer (score 1):

The type erasure (or maybe reference erasure could be better term here) sketch of the approach:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

struct Object { 
    Object() {
        std::cout << "Object()" << std::endl;
    }
    Object(const Object &) {
        std::cout << "Object(const Object &)" << std::endl;
    }
    Object(Object &&) {
        std::cout << "Object(Object &&)" << std::endl;
    }
    Object &operator =(const Object &) {
        std::cout << "Object &operator =(const Object &)" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
    Object &operator =(Object &&) {
        std::cout << "Object &operator =(Object &&)" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

template <class T>
struct RLReferenceWrapper {
    bool is_rvalue;
    T *pnull;
    const T& cref;
    T&& rref;
    RLReferenceWrapper(T&& rref): is_rvalue(true), pnull(nullptr), cref(*pnull), rref(std::move(rref)) { }
    RLReferenceWrapper(const T& cref): is_rvalue(false), pnull(nullptr), cref(cref), rref(std::move(*pnull)) { }

    template <class L>
    void Visit(L l) {
        if (is_rvalue) {
            l(std::move(rref));
        } else {
            l(cref);
        }
    }
};

struct Foo {
    Object m_object;

    virtual void bar(RLReferenceWrapper<Object> wrapper) {
        wrapper.Visit([this](auto&& ref){ 
            m_object = std::forward<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(ref)>>(ref);
        });
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo f;
    f.bar(Object{});
    Object o2;
    f.bar(o2);
}
```

Output:

```
Object()
Object()
Object &operator =(Object &&)
Object()
Object &operator =(const Object &)
```

[[live demo]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xmR695aMthRaKAo2)

Answer (score 0):

an alternative solution might be ( not tested ):

```
template <class T> struct movable{};
template <class T> struct movable<T const&>
{
  movable( movable const& ) = delete;
  movable( T const& r ): ref_{ const_cast<T&>(r) }, movable_{false} {}
  movable( T&& r ): ref_{r}, movable_{true} {}

  auto get() const -> T const& { return ref_; }
  auto move() -> T&& { if( !movable_ ) throw std::runtime_error{"bad move!"}; movable_ = false; return std::move(ref_); }

  template <class V>
  void assign_or_move_to( V& v ) { if( movable_ ) v = move(); else v = get(); }

private:
  T&   ref_;
  bool movable_;
};

struct Foo {
  Object m_object;

  virtual void bar( movable<Object const&> object_ref )
  {
    auto& object = object_ref.get();

    // ...

    object_ref.assign_or_move_to( m_object );

    // or

    if( something ) m_object = object_ref.move();
  }
};
```

that said, I doubt it's worth it, you should still explain us why you refuse to write two bar overloads to begin with ...

Comment: I think you misunderstood my intent (just a little bit). "if (something)" should be automatic. I mean, this if should be based on movable::_movable. The intent here is that I could just write "m_object = object_ref", and the "magic" happens automatically. Why would I have something like this? Because I don't need to duplicate a **lot** of functions. With just a little wrapper, and a little modification in the functions' signature, I can get the needed functionality. Don't you think that this is reasonable?

Comment: @geza avoiding code duplication is seldom a good reason *per se*, especially if it forces you writing bad workarounds and hacks *just* for that. In this case, having the same function doing two contradictory things ( eg promising to not mutate an object / allowing to move it ) is asking for troubles ... anyway, take a look at the edit

Comment: of course, if you *really* want the assignment to happens *auto-magically*, you need to change Object definition ... but IMO, this would be even more dangerous

Comment: I don't really understand. If it is initialized from an lvalue, it won't be modified. If it is initialized from an rvalue, it is moved. No harm done in either way, I see no contradiction here. Why would this be a workaround/hack?

Comment: @gaza, the contradiction manifests inside the function ( and possibly in nested calls ): in a bar(T const&) you can copy the object how many times you want and you can never mutate it directly ( the compiler complains ); conversely, in a bar(T&&) you can move it *at most* once ( if you don't the next copy will be in an unspecified/moved state ) and you can mutate it at will. Now, you want to write the two functions as one, can we guarantee *both* semantics are fulfilled ( now and in the future ) ? sure, but you're on your own and the compiler will not help you anymore ... is it worth it ?

Comment: at least, a solution like the above makes evident that you know what you're doing, and that nothing *magical* happens under the hood ...

Comment: You can treat this function as if it had rvalue reference parameter. I absolutely don't see any problems with that. It's a little bit new semantic, but I don't think it is hard to be accustomed to it. If you want to be explicit, you may want to force users of object_ref to use `std::move` to have move semantics. And if the object stays in place (in the case of object_ref is initialized with lvalue), then it stays. It don't think this matters. There's nothing in the standard about `std::move` semantic at all. With this trick, I can avoid code duplication, decrease code size.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
struct Foo {
    Object m_object;

    void bar(Object& o) { bar_impl(o); }
    void bar(Object&& o) { bar_impl(std::move(o)); }

    template <typename T>
    void bar_impl(T&& object) { 
        // snip ...
        m_object = std::forward<T>(object);
    }
};
```

I think this:

1. Only instantiates bar for Object& and Object&&
2. Only has one instance of the long function
3. Allows template to pick copy-or-move depending on what is passed

It doesn't have a wrapper object or anything, but I think that's OK b/c `T&&` is not an rvalue as such, it's a universal reference as explained here: https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers (thanks Scott!)

Comment: A `std::move` is missing from the second call of `bar_impl`. Otherwise, it's could be a solution for the template case. (offtopic: I now dislike calling these references by a new name. I think it's misleading. When I first saw them, it helped me to understand what's going on, because no good introductory material was available. Now I don't like it, because they are actually not another kind of references at all, && just influences how the template parameter deduced)